# Training a Tensorflow model with data in different shapes

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning

I'm trying to build a Tensorflow model. The input consists of 2 data set:

1. audio files in different lengths encoded to spectrograms represented as ndarrays.
2. ndarray of labels.
   The problem is that the model can not being fed with data in different shapes (in my case, different lengths of audio files).

- Is there any way to train a model with input with different shapes
- I tried to pad all files with zeros at the end in order to increase them as the longest length, and to get all input in the same size. Is it correct?
  Thanks

More information and code about the problem.
for example, I created a tiny dataset:

```
records = ["record_1/record.wav", 
           "record_2/record.wav",
           "record_3/record.wav"]

labels = np.array([1,3,2])
```

I defined a function that loads the files and converts them to spectrograms.
Trying to run this function over my dataset and create one ndarray from it, yields an error since the records are in different lengths.

```
data = [Sp_and_phase(r) for r in records]
[print(d.shape, d.dtype) for d in data]

np.array(data)

>>>(32, 257) float32
>>>(47, 257) float32
>>>(3672, 257) float32
>>>/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:4: VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray.
  after removing the cwd from sys.path.
```

Therefore I changed my datatype to 'object' and had all samples in one ndarray.
however, when I tried to train  a very simple keras model using the function fit(), I got an error:

```
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras import models

data = np.array(data, dtype=object)
print(type(data))
model = models.Sequential([
    layers.Input(shape=(None, 257)),
    layers.Dense(1),     
])

model.summary()

model.compile(
    optimizer='adam',
    loss='mse',
)

history = model.fit(
    data,
    labels,
    batch_size=1,
    epochs=1,
)

>>><class 'numpy.ndarray'>
>>>Model: "sequential_7"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 dense_7 (Dense)             (None, None, 1)           258       
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 258
Trainable params: 258
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

>>>ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type numpy.ndarray).
```

Is there a way to deal with this problem? Any way to train a model on audio files with different lengths?

Comment: this question is off topic for stack overflow as it is not a programming problem. take a look at [tensorflow's ragged tensors](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/ragged_tensor#keras), which are designed for variable-length sequences.

Comment: Why can't the model be fed with audio of different length? Normally you can do that. What is your code, and what is the error?